# What does "large sparse" and "small dense" means?

Tags: machine-learning, rnn

In a paper I'm reading today it's written :

> For a fixed parameter count, we discover that large sparse WaveRNNs
>   significantly outperform small dense WaveRNNs and that this
>   relationship holds up to high level of sparsity greater than 96 %.

What does it all mean ? Does it have something to do with the number of layers ?

Comment: ... what paper?

Comment: @SeanOwen Efficient Neural Audio Synthesis